# How do websites such as Twitch, YouTube, Twitter, and Reddit load pages and change the URL without actually reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On other sites, when you click a link for example, the page goes blank for a second and you see a loading indicator in your browser tab. However, on sites like YouTube and Twitch, when you click a link, you are sent to the page without the loading indicator with no white screen at all.

How is this done? I know it's related to Ajax, but what would be a modern approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

It's called SPA - single-page application. The content of the page is rewritten without reloading. The content is being fetched in the background using ajax and then applied to the page with a bit of help from a frontend framework.

If you want to know more just google for *single-page application*.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the URL in the address bar without causing a page reload using the [`History.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) API.

> history.pushState(state, title, url);